# Flurry takes 4 seconds to start on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, flurry

I've implemented Flurry Analytics in my app, followed the instructions to put the code like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CFAbsoluteTime start_flurry = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    [Flurry startSession:@"app-key"];
    CFAbsoluteTime end_flurry = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"Time for starting Flurry: %2.5f seconds", end_flurry-start_flurry);

    return YES;
}
```

I've noticed very slow launch times so I have timed it using CFAbsoluteTime and its showing 4 seconds to start Flurry. This is preventing my app from loading the interface and is really frustrating.

Is there another place in the code I can put this 'startSession' code to allow my interface to load first?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've placed it in a background queue (i think!) like this:

like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    CFAbsoluteTime start_flurry = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:NO];
    [Flurry startSession:@"HYKYDWTY6CQK2X9D3W9D"];
    CFAbsoluteTime end_flurry = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"Time for starting Flurry: %2.5f seconds", end_flurry-start_flurry);
});
```

Is that the right method?

Comment: Do it on the background thread.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it using dispatch_async - edited my original question. Is that the correct way?

Comment: i might doubt if it will work precisely with background thread or not as in flurry doc they have said "Flurry recommends calling Flurry Analytics from the main thread. Flurry Analytics is not supported when called from other threads."   https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my edited question, I've solved this by loading it on the background thread.